# ¿Qué hace la estrella `*` como argumento de una función y cómo se usa en Python?

Tags: python, operador

¿Qué hace el operador estrella * en Python cuando se usa como argumento en funciones como `zip(*x)` o `fcn(**k)`?

- ¿Cómo lo maneja internamente el intérprete?
- ¿Afecta el rendimiento? ¿Es rápido o lento?
- ¿Cuando es útil y dónde no lo es?
- ¿Hay que usarlo al definir una función o al llamarla?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La estrella `*` desempaqueta una secuencia/colección en argumentos posicionales, pudiendo usarse al invocar una función:

```
def sumar(a, b):
    return a + b

values = (1, 2)

s = sumar(*values)
```

Esto desempaqueta la tupla; lo que finalmente se ejecuta es:

```
s = sumar(1, 2)
```

La doble estrella `**` hace lo mismo, pero con diccionarios y argumentos con nombre:

```
values = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
s = sumar(**values)
```

Esto toma el diccionario y lo convierte en serie de `llave=valor`. El resultado es la ejecución de:

```
s = sumar(a=1, b=2)
```

Estrella y doble estrella se pueden combinar:

```
def sumar(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

values1 = (1, 2)
values2 = { 'c': 10, 'd': 15 }
s = sumar(*values1, **values2)
```

se ejecutará como:

```
s = sumar(1, 2, c=10, d=15)
```

También se puede aplicar a generadores:

```
s = sumar(*range(4)) -> 6
```

y dentro de tuplas, listas y diccionarios:

```
*range(4), 4   -> (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) # Con la coma se considera una tupla.
[*range(4), 4] -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
{*range(4), 4} -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{'x': 1, **{'y': 2}} -> {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

**En la definición de una función**

Además se puede definir funciones con argumentos del tipo `*x` y `**y`. Esto permite que la función acepta cualquier cantidad de argumentos posicionales y/o argumentos con nombre, sin tener que individualizarlos específicamente.

Ejemplo:

```
def sumar(*values):
    s = 0
    for v in values:
        s = s + v
    return s

s = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

También usando `**`:

```
def get_a(**values):
    return values['a']

s = get_a(a=1, b=2)      # retorna 1
```

asi se puede indicar una gran número de argumentos opcionales sin tener declararlos.

También se pueden combinar:

```
def sumar(*values, **options):
    s = 0
    for i in values:
        s = s + i
    if "neg" in options:
        if options["neg"]:
            s = -s
    return s

s = sumar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)            # retorna 15
s = sumar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=True)  # retorna -15
s = sumar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=False) # retorna 15
```

**Referencia rápida**

Dados

```
tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)
lis = [5, 6, 7, 8]
dic = {'x': 9, 'y': 10, 'z': 11}
s = {12, 13, 14, 15}
```

entonces

```
print(*tup) -> print(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(*lis) -> print(5, 6, 7, 8)
print(*dic) -> print(x, y, z)
print(*s)   -> print(12, 13, 14, 15)

def simple(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

simple(**dic) -> simple(x=9, y=10, z=11)
```

Referencias:

[4.7.5. Desempaquetando una lista de argumentos](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

[PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Comment: como anotación, es habitual que si se usa este metodo al definir funciones tomen el nombre de *args y **kwargs

Comment: Aunque se puede sacar por lógica, otra segunda anotación, sería que cuando se usa en funciones, finalizan los argumentos posicionales, es decir si definimos una función: ```func1(a, b, *args, d): #etc``` no estaría permitido llamarla ```func1(10,20, "a","b", 100)``` ya que *"d"* pasaría a ser un argumento tipo "keyword" (clave) y tendríamos que llamarlo a la función así: ```func1(10,20,"a","b", d=100)```

Comment: @RubialesAlberto. Vale. Como norma siempre sigo los patrones propuestos por el lenguaje (como `func1(a, b, *args, **kwargs)`), lo que simplifica la vida, evita caer en errores y ayuda a la comprensión del código por terceros.