# Imprimir la primera palabra sin coindidencia en py3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    f=input("Introduce una frase: ")
    c=0
    vacio=""
    a=0

    while a==0:
        for i in range(len(f)):

            for j in range(len(f)):

                if f[i]==f[j]:
                    c+=1
                
            if c==1:#aca es 1 porque siempre se va a repetir si o si una vez el caracter i
                vacio+=f[i]
                a=1
            else:
                c=0          

    print(vacio)           
main()
```

Lo que necesito es imprimir el primer caracter sin coincidencia dentro de una frase. Tengo un error dentro del while porque no se muy bien como salirme de el(no puedo usar break). Si me ayudan les agradeceria muchop <3
ej:

> > > introduce una frase: hola

la primera letra sin coincidencia es h

Comment: ¿Qué significa "sin coincidencia"? ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo con la entrada y el resultado esperado?

Comment: ahi le agregue un ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Python es maravilloso.

El método es recorrer la cadena y en cada iteración, formar una nueva frase excluyendo el caracter actual. Si el caracter no aparece en la frase recortada, significa que es único y ahi paramos.

La expresión `[*frase[:i], *frase[i+1:]]` forma una frase sin el caracter en la posición i-esima. Revisar [¿Qué hace la estrella `*` como argumento de una función y cómo se usa en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399534/qu%c3%a9-hace-la-estrella-como-argumento-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-y-c%c3%b3mo-se-usa-en-python)

```
frase = input("Su frase: ")
i = 0
while frase[i] in [*frase[:i], *frase[i+1:]]:
    i += 1
if i < len(frase):
    print(f"La primera letra única es {frase[i]}")
else:
    print("no hay letra unica")
```

**Demo**

```
Su frase: la mama lava la ropa
La primera letra única es v
```

Comment: muchas gracias <3

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!, he leído tu pregunta y me ha parecido un pequeño reto muy interesante, resuelvo el código que mostraré a continuación sin usar break como especificabas en la pregunta y tampoco he usado ninguna función especial de Python por si en su caso no deseabas usarla y querías hacerlo a mano. Aquí te muestro el código:

```py
def main():
    #declaramos variables
    contador = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    #bandera que se encargar de especificar cual es el primer carácter que no se ha repetido 
    primera_coincidencia = False
    
    f=input("Introduce una frase: ")
    
    #Recorremos la frase
    while i < len(f):
        while j < len(f):
            
            #Si f[i] es igual a f[j], ej.: palabra "hola" --> (suponiendo que i es 0 y j es 1) f[h] == f[o]
            if f[i] == f[j]: #Basicamente, comprobamos si coinciden alguna letra
                pass #Si coincide dejamos que pase
            else: #Pero si no coincide sumamos 1 al contador
                contador+=1
            j+=1
        
        #el contador+1 es porque siempre va a haber una letra que va a coincidir, esta coincidencia es la letra que se esta comprobando que en el momento que se compruebe con ella misma el contador no sumará uno cuando esta comprobación no sería valida y debería sumar uno, al no hacerlo, le sumo manualmente uno en la comparación.
        
        if contador+1 == len(f) and primera_coincidencia == False: #Si el contador de no coincidencias es igual a todas las letras que contienen la palabra significa que ninguna letra coinciden con las demás letras de la palabra, entonces, se imprime el siguiente mensaje y se cambia la bandera llamada primera_coincidencia a verdadero.
        #Se cambia a verdadero por si alguna otra letra tampoco coincide con con ninguna otra letra de la palabra, esta ya no se imprime en pantalla porque no es la primera NO coincidiente con las demás, ya sería la segunda.
            print("El primer caracter que no se ha repetido es:", f[i])
            primera_coincidencia = True

        i+=1
        j = 0
        contador = 0
            
main()
```

Aquí dejo una captura con la comprobación de que el código funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

Un saludo!

Comment: muchas gracias <3